# Prove that $g(x, y) = {1\over2} x(x-1) + y$ is bijection

Tags: number-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics, integers

I'm reading the proof of Munkres that the product $Z_+ \times Z_+$ is countable. In my opinion, this proof is quite original and interesting.

The basic idea inside the proof is that: Suppose $A$ is the subset of $Z_+ \times Z_+$ consisting of pairs $(x, y)$ for which $y \le x$. Then we build 2 bijections: one from $Z_+ \times Z_+$ onto $A$, and another one from $A$ onto $Z_+$. The first bijection is: (which is very easy)
$$ f(x, y) = (x + y -1, y)$$

And the second bijection is (which is the one I got stuck):
$$g(x, y) =  {1\over2} x(x-1) + y$$

So to prove that $g(x, y)$ is a bijection, we need to prove that for every positive integer $a$, this equation has a unique positive integer solution which satisfies $y \le x$:
$${1\over2} x(x-1) + y = a$$

But I can't find any clue to solve it. Can anybody give me a hint? Thanks so much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers $T_x=(1/2)x(x-1)$ for $x=1,2,3,\cdots$ are the triangular numbers $0,1,3,6,10,\cdots.$ Given a natural number $a \in \{1,2,3,\cdots\}$ there is then a unique term $T_x$ for which $T_x < a \le T_{x+1}.$ Here $a-T_x \le T_{x+1}-T_x=x$ which determines $y$ as being that difference.

Comment: Very clever. Thanks a lot

Comment: You may be interested in "Cantor's pairing function" which if I recall assumes the natural numbers start at $0$.

Answer (score 5):

The key observation is that
$$
 \frac 12 x(x-1) = 1 + \ldots + (x-1) 
$$
is the sum of the first $(x-1)$ positive integers.

So $g$ maps each "vertical strip" in $A$ to a range of consecutive
integers:
$$
\begin{aligned}
 (1, 1) &\to 1 \\
 (2, 1), (2,2) &\to 2, 3 \\
 (3, 1) \ldots (3,3) &\to 4 \ldots 6 \\
 (4, 1) \ldots (4,4) &\to 7 \ldots 10 \\
 &\text{etc.}
\end{aligned}
$$
For $a \in Z_+$, the point $(x, y)$ defined by
$$
\begin{aligned}
   x &= \max \{ t \in Z_+ \mid \frac 12 t(t-1) < a \} \\
   y &=  a - \frac 12 x(x-1)
\end{aligned}
$$
satisfies $(x, y) \in A$ and $g(x, y) = a$, which proves
that the mapping is a bijection.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I think I got it now!

Comment: @Beginner: Thanks for fixing the error!